# How make a scalable zoom on axis boundary for a time series

Tags: java, android, zooming, androidplot

I develop a graph to display a temperature in time.
I don't know how to make a scalable zoom time axis with android plot.

I'm using this function to set limit border but it take only number param :
I receive i simpleDateFormat as data time.

```
plot.getOuterLimits().set(minX : 0, maxX 9, minY : 0, maxY : 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Androidplot docs have a [section about enabling pan & zoom](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/xyplot.md#pan--zoom).

For example, you could enable horizontal pan/zoom:

```
PanZoom.attach(plot, PanZoom.Pan.HORIZONTAL, PanZoom.Zoom.STRETCH_HORIZONTAL);
```

As far as setting the limits goes, it helps to remember that internally Androidplot is treating all values as numbers.  Without seeing more code I can only assume that you are actually using epoch time long values on the x axis. Based on that assumption you can do this:

```
Date minTime = new Date(...) // earliest date to display
Date maxTime = new Date(...) // latest date to display
plot.getOuterLimits().set(minTime.getTime(), maxTime.getTime(), yourMinY, yourMaxY);
```