# How to Make AndroidPlot Pan Correctly with a TimeAxis

Tags: plot, androidplot

I can implement panning all right on a plot where the x values are relatively small numbers.

```
PanZoom.attach(mPlot, PanZoom.Pan.HORIZONTAL, PanZoom.Zoom.NONE);
```

(I only want horizontal panning, no zoom.)

The same code does not work if the x values are times as from Date.getTime(). These are milliseconds and hence [very] large numbers. The panning does not work. At best it zooms the whole plot out with considerable space at either end, and panning does not move it. At worst the curves disappear completely, and panning does not change the axis labels.

I have tried setting the outerLimits

```
mPlot.getOuterLimits().set(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

That does not help, and I am not finding anything else on the Internet, except there is a similar issue (with no accepted answers) at [How make a scalable zoom on axis boundary for a time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088613/how-make-a-scalable-zoom-on-axis-boundary-for-a-time-series). I think I have provided more information than in that question.

Any help would be appreciated.